# why wont pygame quit?

Tags: python, exit, python-idle, quit

The game freezes instead of quitting. I have to exit from Idle. Any ideas on what to do?

```
def quit_game():
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

            sys.exit()
quit_game()
```

Comment: Running a file from an Idle editor is intended to be similar to running the file from the command line with `python -i path_to_file.py`.  If you run your game with the above code with `python -i` at a command line, does it do the same as you reported (freeze instead of quitting)?

Comment: I just had a pygame programmer try the experiment I suggested (with 3.4 on Win 7) and indeed the game window freezes while the command window shown an interactive >>> prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This is an IDLE bug. I would recommend using a real IDE such as pycharm. However to fix this issue, have a look at the [pygame FAQ](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions). They offer this solution:

```
# ... running = True
while running:
    event = pygame.event.wait ()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False  # Be IDLE friendly
pygame.quit ()
```

Comment: The fact that Idle catches SystemExit is a design decision, not a bug.  It is probably not unique to Idle.  It is usually a plus for users, even if not when running PyGame. Perhaps the details of behavior could be tweeked.  I think the FAQ is wrong in the speculation about keeping references.  I know it is wrong about the claimed difference between starting with 'Edit with Idle' and the Idle Start menu icon.

Comment: The game window freeze behavior is how python itself behaves with -i passed.  See my comments to the question. It is not an Idle bug.  Idle is a real IDE, even if not as complicated or sophisticated in most way as PyCharm.

Comment: Those are good points I wasn't actually aware of, thanks. (However IDLE is surely just a text editor and shell combo? -- irrelevant to the problem however)

Answer (score 0):

It may work....

```
def quit_game():
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
    quit_game()
```